# Conda path no such directory

Tags: python, path, directory, anaconda, conda

I can't use any conda commands. I set the environment paths from `where python` and `where conda` in Command Prompt, but it still doesn't work (see screenshot). I get the same error when I try it in the anaconda prompt:

```
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\Rebecca\Anaconda3\Library\bin\..\..\bin\conda': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

[image: Conda error]

Edit: I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `~/.bashrc` in a terminal. Go to the path given and correct the `conda.sh` path.
In your case, you will need to replace the `\-slashes` with `/-slashes`.

I hope that is all and this helped.
Otherwise I recommend reinstalling.

Comment: When I run `C:\Users\Rebecca>~/.bashrc`, I get the error
`'~' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Yes, I got `The system cannot find the bath specified`. I tried reinstalling as you suggested, and that seemed to work